# HTML - Divison over edge of screen

Tags: html, css

I have something like this at the top of the `<body>`

```
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: #FF0000; height: 10px"></div>
```

Unfortunately you (as a user) are able to scroll a little bit further **over the edge** of the screen and you see the ugly background of my `body` element

Is there any way to get my division to reach a few pixels (50-100px) over the top edge of the normally visible window (non Javascript preferred)?

Comment: you might have padding on the body or an inherited margin on your div that is causing the body to be wider than the div.

Comment: try to add related, yet simplified version of ur **HTML** and **CSS** to let people reproduce the problem. Any online version of this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqzrjhc8/ This is basically my setup. But jsfiddle doesn't really show my problem. Imagine you are on your phone in most of the cases you can scroll up to the page and when you try to scroll further up you can't scroll much higher, but still a little bit (a few pixels). When you release your finger your browser snaps back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a little hard to understand but I think I know what you are trying to ask.

To fix your problem, why don't you try **applying the same color as the top bar to the `<html>`'s `background-color`**. So even if the user holds and drags down from the top of the screen, he will see the same color as the top bar(which is actually the `<html>`'s background color).

Try this and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: You are right, this is my problem. But I don't want to change the background color of my html page, I think it's not that much of a problem anymore.

Comment: You'll get my '*Correct answer*' though.